# Is it possible to undo import in oracle 11g done using sql plus? If possible how to do it?

Tags: sql, import, oracle11g, sqlplus, undo

I have done import of database from .sql file into my database using import command in sql plus. I'm using Oracle 11g. Is it possible to UNDO it? If possible how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can undo it.

I think you will just have to DROP the database by running following commands :

1.`SHOW DATABASES;`Find your database name in the list,then

2.`DROP DATABASE database_name;`